# javascript code runs in another html that does not have javascript codes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have prepared two similar pages. One have jQuery codes that react against scroll event, another one <s>does not have any scripts in html.</s> just include jQuery and jQuery mobile.
After jumping from first page to second page, still jQuery codes written in first page works in second page, though second page does not have <s>any scripts.</s> such scripts. 
Could somebody tell me why jQuery codes run in second page ?

I will show code as below. 
index.html is first page and indexb.html is second page.

```
<!-- INDEX.HTML -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<title>Floating Action Button Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var offset = 220;
    var duration = 500;
    jQuery(document).scroll(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
            jQuery('.back-to-top').fadeIn(duration);
            jQuery('h2').css('color','#f00');
        } else {
            jQuery('.back-to-top').fadeOut(duration);
            jQuery('h2').css('color','#000');
        }
    });

    jQuery('.back-to-top').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, duration);
        return false;
    })
});
</script>

<section data-role="page" id="pagea">
<header data-role="header">
<h1>PAGE A</h1>
<div class="ui-btn-right">
<a id="logoutButton" class="headerButton" href="indexb.html" data-role="button">PAGE B</a>
</div>
</header>

<div data-role="content">
<h1>CONTENT</h1>
<p>Page with 'Back-To-Top' button.</p>
<h2>AAA</h2>
<h2>BBB</h2>
<h2>CCC</h2>
<h2>DDD</h2>
<h2>EEE</h2>
<h2>FFF</h2>
<h2>HHH</h2>
<h2>III</h2>
<h2>JJJ</h2>
<h2>KKK</h2>
<h2>LLL</h2>
<h2>MMM</h2>
<h2>NNN</h2>
<h2>OOO</h2>
<h2>PPP</h2>
<h2>QQQ</h2>
<h2>RRR</h2>
<h2>SSS</h2>
<h2>TTT</h2>
</div><!--main-->

<footer data-role="footer">
FOOTER
</footer>

</section>


<!-- ############################################################## -->

<a href="#" class="back-to-top">Back To Top</a>

</body>
<style>
.back-to-top {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 2em;
    right: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: rgba(235, 235, 235, 0.80);
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 1em;
    display: none;
}

.back-to-top:hover {
    background-color: rgba(135, 135, 135, 0.50);
}
</style>
</html>
```

```
<!-- INDEXB.HTML -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<title>Floating Action Button Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- PAGEB -->

<section data-role="page" id="pageb">
<header data-role="header">
<h1>INDEX</h1>
<div class="ui-btn-right">
<a id="logoutButton" class="headerButton" href="index.html" data-role="button">PAGE A</a>
</div>
</header>

<div data-role="content">
<h1>CONTENT</h1>
<p>Page without 'Back-To-Top' button</p>
<h2>aaa</h2>
<h2>bbb</h2>
<h2>ccc</h2>
<h2>ddd</h2>
<h2>eee</h2>
<h2>fff</h2>
<h2>ggg</h2>
<h2>hhh</h2>
<h2>iii</h2>
<h2>jjj</h2>
<h2>kkk</h2>
<h2>lll</h2>
<h2>mmm</h2>
<h2>nnn</h2>
<h2>ooo</h2>
<h2>ppp</h2>
<h2>qqq</h2>
<h2>rrr</h2>
<h2>sss</h2>
</div><!--main-->

<footer data-role="footer">
FOOTER
</footer>

</section>
</body>
</html>
```

When open indexb.html first. Of course, there are no effects, but after jumping to index.html jQuery code does not working. I am not sure what shall I do. Help me, please.

Comment: _"second page does not have any scripts"_, but you do have scripts on the second page (jquery, and jquery mobile), so why wouldn't jQuery codes work?

Comment: Both pages have scripts.

Comment: I think what he means is the document.ready function of the first doc also works for the second doc. Is that what you mean OP?

Comment: I am sorry. Yes, both pages have scripts. My question is: Why script in first page works after jumping to the second page?

Comment: Ideally such issue doesn't occur. Try clearing your browser cache and then execute.

Comment: There is no way!! 
First:  ctrl + f5  and try again. If this still occurs  at the second page press ctrl + u (check the source of the document ) and look for the script from first page. It must be there if it's not in browser cache.